# cut cumulative percentages into multiple columns

Tags: r

[Edited] I'd like to know how to cut a range of columns by the cumulative percentages. I have a dataset that has a range of columns the with total number of survey respondents for each level of education, 1-5. Some rows have no respondents in the 4 or 5th columns, since the survey did not ask about that level of education (only if they completed school beyond the 3rd).

I would like to consolidate 5 columns into 4 columns, based on the cumulative percentages of each column (so that each row has complete columns and they are ordered by the relative of amount of education)

Here are some mock data (`edu1_fav` means the respondent at education level 1 favored a certain law in a certain year):

```
set.seed(123)
Data <- data.frame(
  year = sample(1998:2004, 200, replace = TRUE),
  edu1_fav = sample(1:10, 200, replace = TRUE),
  edu2_fav = sample(1:10, 200, replace = TRUE),
  edu3_fav = sample(0:5,  200, replace = TRUE),
  edu4_fav = sample(0:5,  200, replace = TRUE),
  edu5_fav = sample(0:5,  200, replace = TRUE),
  edu1_opp = sample(1:10, 200, replace = TRUE),
  edu2_opp = sample(1:10, 200, replace = TRUE),
  edu3_opp = sample(0:5,  200, replace = TRUE),
  edu4_opp = sample(0:5,  200, replace = TRUE),
  edu5_opp = sample(0:5,  200, replace = TRUE)
)
head(Data)
#   year edu1_fav edu2_fav edu3_fav edu4_fav edu5_fav edu1_opp edu2_opp edu3_opp
# 1 2000        3       10        1        2        1        9        3        3
# 2 2003       10        2        4        2        3        9        3        0
# 3 2000        7       10        1        0        0        5        1        1
# 4 2004        6        6        1        0        5        8        5        4
# 5 2004        5        4        1        1        5        5        3        4
# 6 1998        9        5        4        5        2       10        8        0
#   edu4_opp edu5_opp
# 1        0        0
# 2        5        0
# 3        1        0
# 4        4        3
# 5        3        2
# 6        0        3
```

I *think* the first 3 columns of the first row of the final data frame would look something like this:

```
year    edu1_fav   edu2_fav    edu3_fav edu4_fav
2000    10          5           9       7
pct     0.32    0      .48         0.77     1
```

Basically, the columns are shortened from 5 to 4 columns. I used cumulative percentages in excel to manually calculate that rows.

I asked this question previously, but it was badly framed. I hope his makes more sense. I've looked for several tutorials, but have been unable to find how to produce cumulative percentages by row, and then consolidate columns based on those percentages.

Comment: It is not clear about `consolidate 5 columns into 3 columns`

Comment: And please clarify if your expected output is actually based on the sample data (I guess, it's not? - Would be better if it was)

Comment: Why not use, eg, the 1st line from `head(Data)` to illustrate what the desired output would look like? That will be clearer for people.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The expected output is just a mockup. The reason I want 3 instead of 5 columns is because there are at least 3 columns worth of data for every single row. So, in the rows with 3 columns, I know what the high and low education levels are. I wouldn't know how to mutate 3 to 5 columns, but do know what it means to go from 5 - 3. As for the expected output, I'm not sure how to turn the sample data into that, but I thought it would be illustrative to give at least something. Does this help? thanks!!

Comment: @tom It would be better if you update the post with the real expected values for the first 6 rows.  For me, it is not clear.

Comment: You have to explain what steps you want to take to go from 5 to 3 columns! Currently, you only say you know what it takes but that is no help at all.

Comment: Ok i updated it! did a little manual calculations in excel but i think i'm on a better track. hope this is more clear.